# Wordpress script to change settings across multisite network

Tags: php, database, wordpress, multisite

I want to be able to write a script that will change a setting, or group of settings across a wordpress multisite network. At the minute, I have no idea how to do this so am looking for a starting place.

An example would be, if I have a plugin installed on my network and wish to change a single setting for that plugin on every site, is there a way I can run a script to make this change in the database rather than me have to manually do it across all sites?